# ajax search displaying id onclicking the name

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

this code displays the name as i type, as i type it gives suggestion of names and when clicked on it it displays the result in the textbox.but i want to display the id related to that name from database when i clicked on that name from the dropdown option. please help

```
<input type="text" name="st_id"  id="st_id" ><div id="txtHint"     style="position: absolute; width:390px ;"></div>
```

ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#st_id").keyup(function () {

        var search = $(this).val();

        if (search != '') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajaxcode.php",
                data: {search: search},
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#txtHint").fadeIn();
                    $("#txtHint").html(data);

                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

php code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["search"])) {
   $display = '';
    $q = $_POST["search"];
    $stmt = $DBconnect->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE First_name   LIKE :sh ");
    $stmt->bindValue(':sh', '' . $q . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $display = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';
    foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        if ($row) {
            $display .= '<li>' . $row["First_name"] . '  ' . $row["Middle_name"] . '  ' . $row["Last_name"] . '</li>';
        } else {
            $display .= '<li>name not found</li>';
        }
    }
    $display .= '</ul>';
    echo $display;
}
?>
```

Comment: I am finding your question quite confusing... you want the `id` of `<input>` ? or do you want to use the **name** and lookup the `id` of the name from the database?

Comment: Include the ID in the `foreach` loop. Then add JS to have it show when clicked. What have you tried?

Comment: you need to show the relevant name when search when you pick one name from that suggestion .instead of name it should be displayed person id  in text box  is it ?

Comment: yes i want the id from database matching the name to be displayed in the textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most naive way I can come up with is adding an id to the top `ul`

```
<ul id="name_suggestion" class="list-unstyled">
```

and the id to the `<li>` tag with a `data-` attr

```
$display .= '<li data-user-id = '. $row["id"] . '>'.$row["First_name"].'  '.$row["Middle_name"].'  '.$row["Last_name"].'</li>';
```

Then add an a click listener to the li:

```
$('#name_suggestion li').on('click', function(e){
    let val = $(this).attr('data-user-id');

    $('#st_id').val(val);
});
```